# Keras - custom infinite data generator with shuffle

Tags: python, numpy, keras, generator

**Disclaimer**: I think question is not related to the keras directly and is more about general behavior of generators in python

I am trying to build a custom data generator for Keras. I do this since build-in image data generators support only the classification tasks while I am trying to solve a regression task with images as inputs.

First of all, I upload a text file which contains img path and target variable Y into the dataframes, then I shuffle them:

```
train, test = AnnoParser.get_data(input_path)
train = train.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

`AnnoParser` just parses text file and returns Pandas Dataframes.

Then I define my data generator:

```
def get_data_generator(array, resized_width, resized_height, mode):
    while True:
        if mode == 'train':
            array = array.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
            augment = True

        for img_path, img_hype in array:
            try:
                img = data_augment(img_path,resized_width, resized_height, augment)

                yield np.copy(img), np.copy(img_hype)
```

Since I am using `while True` loop I expect it to be infinite. As you see I also reshuffle input array each time to ensure that the sample is random. `DataAugment` function takes img path as input, loads the image from this path and resizes it to specified sizes, returning the image itself (cv2 is used).

Finally I create a generator instance and use it later:

```
data_gen_train = DataGenerator.get_data_generator(train, 224, 224, "train")
```

Now, as far as I understand under the hood each time I will be calling `next(data_gen_train)` generator will shuffle the original `train` array and draw next value from the execution result. Hence as I understand my generator supposed to be able to infinitely draw images from the population of all image pathes I have in my original dataset.

But seems like the generator still often throws the StopIteration exception. I am not sure why. Can anyone explain?

**UPDATE**

As requested, also below you can find how use the generator to fit model. As you see I first fetch a bunch of images into array so that I can train network in minibatches. Then I just feed minibatches into the network and evaluate losses.

As far as I see generator breaks after a while, not on a very first couple of iterations. I suspect that under the hood it just does a single path over all available records (those which can be yielded by generator) and then throws the iteration exception.

```
optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-5)

model = DenseNet(reduction=0.5, weights_path=weights_path)
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=optimizer)

iter_num = 0

accuracy_monitor = []
accuracy_for_epoch = []
start_time = time.time()

best_loss = np.Inf


print('Starting training')

for epoch_num in range(num_epochs):
    progbar = generic_utils.Progbar(epoch_length)
    print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch_num + 1, num_epochs))
    while True:
        #keep training untill end of epoch, if end of epoch - check result
        if len(accuracy_monitor) == epoch_length:
            print("Average accuracy is {} for {} previous iterations", str(np.mean(accuracy_monitor)), epoch_length)
            accuracy_for_epoch.append(np.mean(accuracy_monitor))
            accuracy_monitor = []


        X = np.ndarray((batch_size,224,224,3))
        Y = np.ndarray((batch_size))

        i = 0
        #building a batch
        for img,hype in data_gen_train:
            X[i,] = img
            Y[i] = hype
            i+=1
            if i == batch_size:
                break

        loss = model.train_on_batch(x= X, y = Y)
        accuracy_monitor.append(loss)
        iter_num +=1
        progbar.update(iter_num,[('Loss', np.mean(accuracy_monitor[:iter_num]))])
        if iter_num == epoch_length:
            accuracy_for_epoch.append(np.mean(accuracy_monitor))
            curr_loss = np.mean(accuracy_monitor)
            print('Elapsed time: {}'.format(time.time() - start_time))
            print("Regressor accuracy over epoch: {}", curr_loss)
            if curr_loss < best_loss:
                print('Total loss decreased from {} to {}, saving weights'.format(best_loss,curr_loss))
                best_loss = curr_loss
                model.save_weights(weights_path)
            start_time = time.time()
            iter_num = 0
```

Comment: Could you show the code of fitting? Does generator breaks after first batch / epoch?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Seems like the problem comes from the fact that I was using Pandas Dataframes to pass them over into the datagenerator. If I instead convert them to numpy array it works:

```
train = train.as_matrix()
np.random.shuffle(train)

#then go on with generator creation
```